# object doesnot support this property error while opening a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks. workbook1 is my destination workbook(DWB) and workbook 2 is my original workbook (OWB). My OWB is in the network folder.

I am trying to copy all the contents of OWB to DWB.

Below is my code I have tried so far. But in the line below, I get a error

> object doesnot support this property
>
> Set OWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filepath)

```
Sub Extract()
Dim DWB As Workbook
Dim OWB As Workbook
Dim path1 As String
Dim path2 As String
Dim filepath As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim Lastcol As Long
Dim header As String
Dim cell As Range

Set DWB = ThisWorkbook

path1 = DWB.Path
filepath = "\\cw.wan.com\root" & "\Loc\04_Infol\pivot.xlsx"
Set OWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filepath)

LastRow = OWB.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Lastcol = OWB.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = 1 To Lastcol
    header = OWB.Worksheets(1).cell(1, i).Value

        With DWB.Worksheets("T").Range("A4:Y4")
        Set cell = .Find(header, LookIn:=xlValues)
        End With

            If Not cell Is Nothing Then
            OWB.Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(LastRow, i)).Copy Destination:=DWB.Worksheets("T").Cells(5, cell.Column)
                Else
                'handle error
            End If
    Next i
    OWB.Close savechanges:=Fasle
End Sub
```

Comment: If you write `MsgBox filepath` before the error, copy exactly what you see to your Windows Explorer  and press Enter, what would happen?

Comment: This will error: `header = OWB.Worksheets(1).cell(1, i).Value` as it should be `Cells` and not `Cell`.

Comment: @Rory thank you it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have some problem like this, try to minimze the code and isolate the problem. Thus, in your case, the minimal problem would look like:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim owb As Workbook
    Set owb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Something\Desktop\MyFile.xlsm")
End Sub
```

Try to make this minimal 2 liner work, then your problem will be fixed. This is the idea behind the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

The error has been tracked down and solved

Still I believe you could take advantage from thorough understanding and usage of `Range` references to both ensure you're correctly referencing the correct one and reduce typing, too

for instance you could code:

```
With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filepath) 'reference wanted workbook
    With .Worksheets(1) 'reference wanted worksheet of referenced workbook
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
        Lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For i = 1 To Lastcol
            header = .Cells(1, i).value

            Set cell = DWB.Worksheets("T").Range("A4:Y4").Find(header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not cell Is Nothing Then
                .Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(LastRow, i)).Copy Destination:=cell.Offset(1)
            Else
                'handle error
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    .Close savechanges:=False
End With
```

where you can also see the recommended minimum parameter explicit setting of `Find()` method, which otherwise would use those from its last call (even from UI!)